# Connect Unity 3D game with cardano

Tags: wallet, nami-wallet, yoroi, decentralized-applications, cardano-address

I am creating a play to game in Unity 3D. What is the best way to authenticate wallet of the users and send cardano native tokens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cardano-unity](https://github.com/fivebinaries/cardano-unity) SDK for this purpose.